# Avoid memory leak on Async timeout

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous

I'm trying to find a memory leak in my application and I want to know if I must (or should) call EndInvoke in case of a timeout. I'm calling a external system and I must have a way to stop waiting if execution is too long:

```
Dim ar As IAsyncResult
Try
  ar = deleg.BeginInvoke(Nothing, New Object)
  If Not ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(getTimeout, False) Then
    'Should I call EndInvoke here
    Throw New Exceptions.TimeoutException
  Else
    response = deleg.EndInvoke(ar)
  End If
Finally
  ar = Nothing
End Try
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do need to call `EndInvoke`. But you can't call it in a timeout situation (or else it would block on the operation, defeating the purpose of asynchronous execution and timeouts).

One option is to toss it into the thread pool. You can pass the `AsyncWaitHandle` to `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` and have the callback call `EndInvoke` (being sure to catch exceptions). However, this approach does not scale (only 64 handles can be outstanding on the thread pool at any given time).

A better option is to use the new `Task` abstraction in .NET 4.0 (also available in .NET 3.5 if you use Rx). It's much easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the server I use is .Net 3.5 and I can't upgrade to .NET 4.0 or install any packages (ex Rx extension) on it. Do you know way to do this with .NET 3.5 only ? Also, you said that I can only have 64 handles in ThreadPool. Do you means 64 handles at the same time ? When a thread complete (or timeout), is the handle released ?

Comment: Rx doesn't need to be installed - it can be just bin-deployed and run on the 3.5 runtime. There isn't a `Task` implementation for 3.5 aside from Rx AFAIK. The 64-handle limit applies to `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`, so it's a limit on the number of async delegates that have already timed out but not yet completed.

Comment: We're finally converting that part of the project to .Net 4 so I'll be able to use the tasks instead. Thanks for the answer.